# Post Multiple Records/Rows with Jquery Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webmethod

i have the following data in dataTable and want to post it by Jquery Ajax. using `ASP.Net WebMethod`

```
|SupplierId| ProductId | Quantity|Price/Unit|
--------------------------------------------
| 1        |   1       |  10    | 50       |
| 1        |   2       |  15    | 130      |
| 1        |   3       |  5     | 150      |
| 2        |   2       |  5     | 150      |
--------------------------------------------
```

how to Pass multiple row to jquery Ajax as data on single click.
i am doing it in the following way, but it inserts only last row.

```
      var proParams={};
      var param = {};
      var rows = $("#QuotationDataTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var aData = $("#QuotationDataTable").dataTable().fnGetData(i);
      param.SupplierId = aData[0];
      param.ProductId = aData[1];
      param.Quantity = aData[2];
      param.UnitPrice = aData[3];
   // Below both lines work similar...
      proParams = {'proParam': param }
   // proParams += {'proParam': param };
       } 

        $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: JSON.stringify(proParams),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: '/Forms/Quotation.aspx/SaveQuotation',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Operation Performed');
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           alert('Operation Failed');
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're overriding `proParams` on each iteration. That's why it keeps yout last item. Try with this

```
var proParams=[]; // <-- declare as array
var param = null;
var rows = $("#QuotationDataTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var aData = $("#QuotationDataTable").dataTable().fnGetData(i);
    param = new Object(); // <-- creates a new object
    param.SupplierId = aData[0];
    param.ProductId = aData[1];
    param.Quantity = aData[2];
    param.UnitPrice = aData[3];
    proParams.push({'proParam': param }); // <-- push a new element into array
}
```

Comment: same problem, only last record is added.

Comment: in firebug it add the first row successful, but when come to 2nd row it overides the first object data with 2nd row, and also adds the new object with same data, and when come to 3rd row it overides the 2 object data of array with 3rd row, and add 3rd object to arrary.

Comment: @Shahid Iqbal: not necessary to have the declaration inside the loop, it is indeed required to initialize `param` though and that's what I did :)